Iteratively calculating the least squares coefficient in Python -- is there anything I can do to speed up my code?
At each time step t, I get a new x_t and y_t. Once there are a total of PERIOD x's and y's, it'll do ordinary least squares and spit out the coefficient. In the code, "benchmark" is the x and "asset" is the y. (This is from finance lingo). The online_calc method does the actual computation.

class Beta():

    def __init__(self, PERIOD):
        self.PERIOD = PERIOD
        self.stat = None
        self.benchmark_vec = []
        self.asset_vec = []
    
    def update(self, new_benchmark, new_asset):
        """
            assumes that on update, neither new_asset nor new_benchmark are none 
        """
        if new_benchmark is not None and new_asset is not None:
            self.benchmark_vec.append(new_benchmark) 
            self.asset_vec.append(new_asset) 

        if len(self.benchmark_vec)>self.PERIOD:
            self.benchmark_vec=self.benchmark_vec[1:]  

        if len(self.asset_vec)>self.PERIOD:
            self.asset_vec=self.asset_vec[1:]   

        if len(self.benchmark_vec)==self.PERIOD and len(self.asset_vec)==self.PERIOD:
            self.stat=self.online_calc()

        return self.stat
    
    def online_calc(self):
        asset_ar      = np.array(self.asset_vec)
        benchmark_ar  = np.array(self.benchmark_vec)

        y = asset_ar[1:]/asset_ar[:-1]-1
        x = benchmark_ar[1:]/benchmark_ar[:-1]-1

        X = x.reshape(-1, 1)
        X = np.concatenate([np.ones_like(X), X], axis=1)
        b = np.linalg.pinv(X.T.dot(X)).dot(X.T).dot(y)
        return b[1]

    

###### example usage
asset_vec=[ 0.01568653, -0.00669479,  0.01140213, -0.00107317, -0.00131155, -0.00333463,
 -0.00114006,  0.00263075, -0.00507337,  0.00712401,  0.00388323]
benchmark_vec=[ 0.01150227,  0.00045742,  0.01114376, -0.00305367,  0.00388245,  0.00323491,
 -0.00449446, -0.00075698, -0.01114904,  0.0147878,   0.00528754]

beta = Beta(4)
output = []          
for b, a in zip(benchmark_vec, asset_vec):
    output.append(beta.update(b, a))

output

I was previously using scipy.stats.linregress to get the coefficient but it was about 50% slower than this (i'm guessing because it also calculates the intercept, p-value, etc). So I am wondering if there are any speed gains i'm leaving on the table.
EDIT: edited code to include example usage

np.linalg.pinv is the expensive part here. It is certainly done in O(n**3). In general, it is pretty efficient thanks to parallel BLAS implementations. The best option is to use math tricks to avoid computing a particularly expensive pinv.

Besides, what is the array dtype? You can use simple precision for better performance. BLAS operations on integer are generally pretty slow (not optimized). It is generally better to provide a minimal reproducible example for performance-related questions.

why not use np.linalg.solve(X.T @ X, X.T @y) instead of np.linalg.inv??

and since this is OLS, i would recommend just solving the problem using scalars instead of matrices. ie b = sum(y*(x - mean(x))/sum((x-mean(x))**2) and a = mean(y) - b*mean(x)

@JérômeRichard I edited the code to include minimal reproducible example. The dtype is float, not integer.

@Onyambu nice! np.linalg.solve(X.T @ X, X.T @y) is twice as fast

@Onyambu b = sum([y*(x - mean_x) for x,y in zip(x,y)])/sum([(x-mean_x)**2 for x in x]) is even faster. thanks!

Also note that instead of computing the coefficients each time, just simply update the already calculated coefficients. ie you do not have to run regression each time. This will be the fastest method

@Onyambu that's unclear to me ... how can i update the already calculated coefficient instead of redoing the regression each time?

I just checked your code. It seems ALL your x and y values are different each time. So you will have to redo the regression. Sometimes if the different value is just the newly added value, while the other values are maintained, you do not have to redo the whole regression but rather do some simple updates

at each step a new x/y is appended and the oldest x/y is removed

I have included a solution which is 10X faster than using np.linalg.solve

Here is an attempt with update. This uses previously calculated values and thus should be faster. If memory is an issue, we could optimize it further by calculating on the fly rather than storing the values and calling them:
class Beta2():

    def __init__(self, PERIOD):
        self.PERIOD = PERIOD
        self.stat = None
        self.benchmark_vec = []
        self.asset_vec = []
        self._x, self._y, self._xx, self._xy = [], [], [], []
        self._sum_x, self._sum_y, self._sum_xx, self._sum_xy = 0,0,0,0
        self._ln = 0
    
    def update(self, new_benchmark, new_asset):
        """
            assumes that on update, neither new_asset nor new_benchmark are none 
        """
        if new_benchmark is not None and new_asset is not None:
            try:
              x = new_benchmark/ self.benchmark_vec[-1] - 1
              y = new_asset / self.asset_vec[-1] - 1
            except:
              x, y = 0, 0
            self._x.append(x)
            self._y.append(y)
            self._xx.append(x * x)
            self._xy.append(x * y)
            self._sum_x += x
            self._sum_xx += self._xx[-1]
            self._sum_y += y
            self._sum_xy += self._xy[-1]
            self.benchmark_vec.append(new_benchmark) 
            self.asset_vec.append(new_asset) 
            self._ln += 1
            
        if (i := self._ln - self.PERIOD + 1) > 0:
            self.online_calc()
            self._sum_x -= self._x[i]
            self._sum_xx -= self._xx[i]
            self._sum_y -= self._y[i]
            self._sum_xy -= self._xy[i]
        
        return self.stat
    
    def online_calc(self):
        numerator = self._sum_xy - self._sum_x * self._sum_y/(self.PERIOD - 1)
        denominator = self._sum_xx - self._sum_x * self._sum_x/(self.PERIOD - 1)
        self.stat = numerator/denominator

    

###### exa
    
beta2 = Beta2(4)
output2 = []          
for b, a in zip(benchmark_vec, asset_vec):
    output2.append(beta2.update(b, a))
    
    

